# java RMI and/or JNDI: binding for objects that are not singletons

Tags: java, rmi, jndi

OK, I get how to use RMI to bind a singleton server object with a well-known name so that other JVMs can find it.

Let's say I have a number of processes, each running a JVM, and each creating an object supporting the `FooRemote` interface, which I wish to expose via RMI. Each process has an unpredictable life cycle that corresponds to something, whether it is from user input, or availability of a resource.

How can I bind these without getting naming collisions? Would using JNDI help?

In effect, what I wish to do is to have a pool of similar objects, each on separate JVMs (reason for doing so is important but beyond the scope of this question). I need a client to be able to enumerate which objects are available, and choose one for further interaction.

(The reason I emphasize the separate JVMs is that if they were all in the same JVM, I could just have a singleton manager that handles the group pool, and make all the group instances accessible through the manager. But I can't do that if the group pool consists of independent instances in separate JVMs. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very effective, but you can have a singleton manager (factory) in each JVM, which creates and enumerates all the objects in the pool that belong to that JVM.

You obviously have to ask them all to get the full picture. This may or may not be what you want depending on your actual use case. While it's accurate, network traffic and delays affect performance drastically, so don't try this if you're querying the pool a lot more than you update it.

Another solution is to turn your client into a server and allow servers to invoke a callback when the status of the objects in the pool change. This solution is probably more efficient in network traffic but is less up-to-date: if one of the servers terminate abruptly, its objects won't be removed from the pool until you actually try to use them and fail. This behaviour can be improved on by a keepalive call and a timeout to keep track of the availability of servers but obviously at the price of increasing the traffic and the complexity of your solution.

Comment: ...but isn't this a chicken & egg issue? Let's say I have 5 JVMs running identical code, with a factory in each JVM. What RMI binding name do I pick for each factory, and how do I enumerate the factories? If I can answer these questions, I can solve my original problem (because in my case I only have one RMI-exported object per JVM).

Comment: You can create a subcontext, pick a random name (an `UUID.randomUUID()` for example) and put the object in that context under the random name. To find all of them you can do an `InitialContext.listBindings()`, which will return all the objects under a context.

Comment: ah: then that solves the problem, then! That's JNDI, right? Could you edit your answer + give me an example or point me towards one online which uses JNDI + RMI w/ subcontexts? this is a bit strange for me.

Comment: Will do, but on second thought, you could do it with a plain `Registry` too, it has a `list()` method. It might be a better option to use something you're more familiar with.

Comment: re: `Registry.list()` -- thanks for the reference... I think JNDI is probably more appropriate if there's hierarchy; a flat list from `Registry.list()` just gives me a bunch of names to wade through. I've been wanting to learn JNDI for a long time but can't seem to find a good introductory reference.

Comment: You can still prefix your names with something so that you can easily identify your objects. The principle is the same, you're just "faking" the namespaces. I'll try to find some good documentation on JNDI too.